# Gmail auth token expires within an hour

Tags: gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-authentication, oauth2client

Gmail auth token expires in one hour, is there any way to increase the lifetime of a token up to 24 hours or more?
I'm using the following method:

```
const oAuth2Client = await new google.auth.OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect);
// got the token
oAuth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You don't need to increase the token TTL since you have a refresh token

First of all take a look into one of the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) examples, and see what happens with the **refresh token**.

The token expiration time is given by the Google API used that's why you've got a **refresh token**. As per the [Google Identity Platform Documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#5.-refresh-the-access-token,-if-necessary.) says `Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to obtain new access tokens.`

Increasing a token lifetime is not necessary, revoking a token when it's no longer necessary is a good practice. Just make sure you follow the [policies](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/policies) that makes your application secure.

Bear in mind, [refresh token might stop working](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration) for one of these reasons:

- The user has revoked your app's access.
- The refresh token has not been used for six months.
- The user changed passwords and the refresh token contains Gmail scopes.
- The user account has exceeded a maximum number of granted (live) refresh tokens.

### Reference

[Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

[OAuth 2.0 Policies](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/policies)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration   this helps much.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to expire, you simply need to refresh it using your refresh token.